# Is kernel essentially an implementation of system calls?

Tags: computer-architecture, operating-systems, os-kernel

In essence, is kernel basically the code that implements a set of system calls?

Comment: sure, why not ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system#Kernel

Answer (score 1):

It's probably more accurate to think of an operating system is an implementation of a virtual machine.

System calls are part of that; they are operations of the virtual machine callable by programs.